# Python / SSL - what user should the process run as if they have read on the private key?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssl, permissions, private-key

There's a nice example in Python here https://speakerdeck.com/markush/ssl-all-the-things-pycon-nz-2016?slide=18 of a server which uses SSL.

At this point ...

[image]

... the process reads a file which contains the private key.

So whatever user the process is running as needs read permission on the private key.

What is the best way to do this from a security point of view ?

Would it be considered bad practice to run the process as 'foo' and give foo read permissions to the PK ? That doesn't sound ideal to me but I just can't see how the type of code in the example can run otherwise ?

I know Apache, for instance, starts as root and then spawns a process under a user with lesser rights. Is that the type of thing that might be done in this circumstance ? Is there a good example of doing that pythonically ?

---

**EDIT**: OK well it seems as if this https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/os.html#os.setuid would allow the process to start as root and then run under a different owner (if that was considered necessary where access to PK is needed like here). Would be interested in any examples of it being done in Python ... as well as any other approaches which might be valid.

---

**EDIT**: Just to add to the comment about the use of `os.setuid` having read this https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/166817/using-the-setuid-bit-properly there do seem to be a number of risks which are difficult to mitigate in my case . I would be interested in any suggestions in how others have managed to write Python scripts which access Private Keys without running as root.

Comment: Sorr, but this is not a programming question. There are sibling sites that handle topics like security and server administration.

Comment: Well the reason I'm asking is that I'm hoping to make use of a facility which Python offers and in particular I am looking for a "Pythonic" (last paragraph) approach to resolving the issue so I don't think it's unreasonable to ask a set of Python programmers how they go about this.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a little confused. A private key file usually has `0600` permission which means it can only be read or writed by current user for security reason. Why do you think "run the process as 'foo' and give foo read permissions to the PK" doesn't sound ideal to you?

Comment: @Sraw - thanks for your response. I suspect it's my confusion, not yours. First of all, until you asked, I was convinced that the the key (owned by root) and had perms of 600 and so only root could read it. I've now found that in fact it's got perms of 644 so that anyone can read it ? Which I don't think is right . I'm puzzled by this because the files were created by an automated process (acme.sh) and I assumed the perms were optimal . Judging by your response I guess you would expect the key to be owned by some user other than root and that whoever owned it would run the process ?

Comment: Well, first tools are not responsible to manage your permission. It's your business. Second, at least on my server, a auto-generated private key does have 644 permission like yours but its parent directory has 700 permission(also auto-generated). So it is still safe. Maybe you should check directories too? Finally, a private key's recommended permission is exactly 600 or even lower(400). You can check your private key used by `ssh user@server`. So I think the best way is "the key to be owned by some user other than root and that whoever owned it would run the process"

Comment: @Sraw: how did we ending up talking about ssh in a question about ssl?

Comment: @JamesKPolk I just take it as an example to explain the recommended private key permission. As it is common for most of us.